# self.presentViewController is not transitioning smoothly and is delayed

Tags: uitableview, swift3, presentviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, cncontactviewcontroller

I'm having some trouble with my project. Everything works fine regarding features and functions, but i've noticed a delayed reaction and rough transition whenever I call self.presentViewController() on MFMessageComposeVC and CNContactsVC.

**When presenting MFMessageComposeViewController**, I call self.present() inside of an IBAction. I'll wait close to a second before it presents itself.

**When presenting CNContactsVC**, I do so inside of a didSelectRowAt() tableView function. Details of a contact from your Contacts are loaded, but it's not smooth the first time. Every time after however it works fine until I reset the app.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**

I've also put both lines of code on the main thread with DispatchQueue.main.async{ self.present(..}

Comment: Have you tried to call `self.presentViewController` on the main thread? like this:      `DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }`

Comment: Ahh yes I forgot to mention that. I've put both code on the main thread by calling DispatchQueue.main.async{}